# When writing in German, to what extent can we permutate phrases?

Tags: grammar-identification

I have written this quite imaginative description, attempting to portray the scene literarily, but I do not know, given that I am only a beginning learner of German, whether my German is unacceptably dominated by my English or not. So abide with me if the sentences sound bizarre and incompatible with common German structure.

> Ich kann mich daran ganz durchsichtig erinnern, dass wie wiltig sie
>   versuchten viel Zeit mit mir zu verbringen. Sie wussten wie schwierig,
>   während des Krieges, allein zu sein war. Sie hatten unser Haus völlig
>   verbrannt, wodurch ich meine ganze Famillie verloren hatte. Ich spürte
>   etwa ärgerlich und entäuscht wenn ich Kinder mit ihren Eltern
>   vorübergehen sah.

I am mostly interested to know whether gerund phrases that are commonly used in English can also be used in German in pretty much the same way.

Ex: I saw people passING by.

Comment: Your example would be "Ich sah Leute vorbeigehen." But your translation is really bad.

Comment: It is not a translation!!!

Comment: Then it is a very bad German and you should burn the source you got it from ;) There is a completely wrong grammar mixed with typos leading to a senseless text. And you should not translate this literarily (although you can transfer some gerunds).

Comment: I was reading this text and thought writing my thoughts in combination with my new words would help me learn better. What do you think of this short excerpt?  Ich hörte die Wagen an dem Gartengitter vorüberfahren, manchmal sah ich sie auch durch die schwach bewegten Lücken im Laub. Wie krachte in dem heißen Sommer das Holz in ihren Speichen und Deichseln! Arbeiter kamen von den Feldern und lachten, daß es eine Schande war.

Comment: @TeXnician I would appreciate it if you could be more specific as to why it is bad German since it is exactly the reason I posted this; to know whether it sounds unnatural and why.

Comment: A good respond would be wether I can use paranthetical modifiers or not, and many other points which, should they be analysed thoroughly, will provide good future refrence points.

Comment: iseybv etibi eiub

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and make a best guess what you tried to express, correcting the worst errors as we go along:

> Ich kann mich daran ganz durchsichtig erinnern, dass wie wiltig (?) sie versuchten viel Zeit mit mir zu verbringen.
>
> *Ich kann mich schwach daran erinnern, dass sie immer versuchten, viel Zeit mit mir zu verbringen.*

*wiltig* is not a German word. I cannot even imagine a word close to it.
Instead of "durchsichtig", that you apparently used to express fading memory, you would use "schwach".

> Sie wussten wie schwierig, während des Krieges, allein zu sein war.
>
> *Ihnen war bewusst, wie schwierig es war, während des Krieges alleine zu sein.*

I changed "wussten" to "...war bewusst..." as this is more a state of mind than knowledge. Also note some "es" had to be added to make sense in German. Word order also needed to be fixed.

> Sie hatten unser Haus völlig verbrannt, wodurch ich meine ganze Famillie verloren hatte.
>
> *Sie hatten unser Haus vollständig niedergebrannt. Dabei habe ich meine gesamte Familie verloren.*

No German would say "verbrennen" on a building. That's "niederbrennen". Also note, you are, apparently, changing the semantics of "Sie" in the context here. That is definitely wrong in both English and German and would need some rework. No way to fix it without more context, though.

> Ich spürte etwa ärgerlich und entäuscht wenn ich Kinder mit ihren Eltern vorübergehen sah.
>
> *Ich spürte Ärger und Enttäuschung, wenn ich Kinder mit ihren Eltern vorübergehen sah.*

*spüren* + an adverb would denote how you do the action in German rather than what you feel. You either need to change to "ich fühlte mich" or, as I did, substantiation.

Comment: Vielen Dank. By durchsichtig I mean to say lucidly. The point you highlighted are really important in that they say I must be wary of collocation and sentence patterns much more.